# Can a kshatriya be born as a brahmin in next birth? Can a woman be born as a male in next birth and vice versa?

Tags: moksha, rebirth, brahmins, kshatriya

What does the scriptures say about rebirth, is a brahmin always a brahmin , kshatriya always a kshatriya ?

Comment: yes the atman can take body of any varna, for example kakabhushund a very great devotee of shree raam was born taking the body of shudra in ayodhya, and in his last birth a a brahmana

Comment: Indeed. Gita 8.6 - Whatever state of being one remembers when he quits his body, O son of Kuntī, that state he will attain without fail.